# Prove that $\sum_{p}\frac{\log p}{p^{s}(p^{s}-1)}$ converges for $R(s)>1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

I am stydying Zagier's paper, Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem. In proof (IV) he states that

$\sum_{p}\frac{\log p}{p^{s}(p^{s}-1)}$

converges for Re(s)>1/2, where $p$ runs over all prime and $s\in\mathbb{C}$. Can anyone help me see why this holds?

I believe I need to use some manner of comparison test, where I prove that $\sum_{n}\frac{\log n}{n^{s}(n^{s}-1)}$ converges for $Re(s)>1/2$ og $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to compare with $n^{-2s}\log n$? That series is $\zeta'(2s)$. Then maybe show it converges absolutely by showing the integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\log t}{t^{1+\epsilon}}\,dt$ converges for all positive $\epsilon$? Because $\log t < t^{\epsilon/2}$ for $t$ large enough